# Rails Logs. How to hide in logs all params from a specific controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 6 app with a Update controller ready for accept JSON Post Requests:

```rb
class ProcessLogsController < ApplicationController
  #...

  # POST /process_logs.json
  def create
   # ... code to save the json in a database ...
  end

  #...
end
```

When a make a Post request with the JSON as a body...

```sh
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:3000/process_logs.json \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "Time": "A UNIX timestamp",
    "Message": "Host Message could be very long, and may include secret info",
    "host": "My Hostname" 
}'
```

I got this in the Logs:

```sh
Started POST "/process_logs.json" for ::1 at 2019-08-13 20:16:37 -0500
Processing by ProcessLogsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"Time"=>"A UNIX timestamp", "Message"=>"[FILTERED]", "host"=>"My Hostname", "process_log"=>{"Time"=>"A UNIX timestamp", "Message"=>"[FILTERED]", "host"=>"My Hostname"}}
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 1)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 1.7ms | Allocations: 227)
```

The output is correct and expected, but I have this corncern with my log:

- The **Parameters** (Line 3) it have the JSON request twice, one for the *request.body* and other for the *process_log* params.
- This controller could have millions of request in a day. And coud have much more keys in the JSON post

So my question is...

Is any way to disable/hide the line **Parameters** on the log for this specific *controller#action*.

I don't want to set the level to :warn because I want to view the other info (Respose code etc..)

Comment: Rails has a class called `backtrace_cleaner` that helps silencing your backtrackes. You should maybe look that way.

Answer (score 0):

actually you can turn off parameters wrapping to `process_log` in params. Look at the documentation for parameters wrapping https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html (documentation for 5.2.x but this behaviour didn't change in rails 6)

Btw if what you are saying is true, you should maybe think about how to make your logs less verbose. With millions of request per day you won't be able to follow this log anyway.

We are using https://github.com/roidrage/lograge for production log in our app. It is less verbose and everything is logged atomically to one long line. It cannot happen that one request starts logging in the middle of the different request (but I would hope rails figured out how to solve this).